# How to click html button on a page?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I got a page (http://www.zaman.com.tr/ahmet-turan-alkan/yav-he-he_2208296.html#tumYazi)

it has limited entries at first page. But when you click moreButton

```
           (< button onclick="loadInfiniteContent();" id="moreButton">Eski Yazıları< /button > )
```

at the bottom of the page the list increases. I want to get the page source code which has all entries  the columlist has. 
I can do with imacros on firefox by looping

```
         VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
          TAB T=1
         TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:moreButton
```

is it possible at c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this in firefox, the browser do ajax request and get the data from the server, you can view this on network tab in your browser dev tools (F12)

As you can see the browser do the request by the following link

http://www.zaman.com.tr/infiniteContent?columnistId=1020&pageNo=4

you can do that request by your c# app to get that partial results manually, just manipulate last parameter pageNo in range you want

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to get final page number?

Comment: It's really depends on API of the service, for e.g. that particular service returns content-length 0 if there is no content, I've perform binary search to evaluate that the current last page is 286

Comment: to know how to perform binary search which subjec do I need to study. thanks again

Comment: Binary search is extremely popular algorithm, you can start from wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: in this site http://hurarsiv.hurriyet.com.tr/yazarlar/ althought I check net tab at firefox, couldnt see link like before. Could you help me? how can I get links for every option values?